# Edit a sharepoint list form with infopath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

LS,

I'm trying to open an sharepoint 2010 list with InfoPath 2010 but when I try this I get the following errormessage: "this feature requires sharepoint server 2010 or greater with infopath forms services enabled". Strangely everything works if I create an empty form with InfoPath, it even publishes to SP2010. My current license is "SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License" so it should work.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit? *"Trying to open a sharepoint 2010 list with Infopath"* <-- you mean the list edit form? You cannot open a list with InfoPath. *empty form with InfoPath, it even publishes to SP2010* <-- you mean you can create a form with InfoPath and publish it to the server. Can you open that form after publishing? Do any other InfoPath forms work? Are InfoPath Form Services configured?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to edit the forms who are behind the sp-list. I'm getting exactly the same message on my box, which you present in your preferred solution. Afaik the infopath form services are configured in the central administration under the "General application settings"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you enable the "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" in the Site Collection features.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to upgrade the farm from Sharepoint Standard to Enterprise?

Make sure that the InfoPath Forms Services are enabled, as the following post suggests:
[Infopath 2010 Beta Sharepoint List](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/25b37151-ce05-4de4-b048-5347e107e57c)

Comment: No I didn't upgrade, the software was downloaded from msdn subscription last week. So it should not be an beta release

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Enterprise features were enabled, InfoPath Forms Services was setup correctly, etc...

What fixed my problem was navigating to the site collection, selecting "Site Settings" from the Site Actions dropdown, Navigating to "Manage site features" under the Site Actions section, then disabling and then re-enabling "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features".

Tons information about this error, but all the fixes were already done on my setup, just needed to remind the collection it really did have these features enabled...